# Java tab order: setFocusTraversalPolicy

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, traversal

My tab order is not doing what I intuitively would suppose it should.  Here is my setFocusTraversalPolicy:

```
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;
```

...

```
p_1.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{
    cmbFnName, cmbFn, txtXoffset, txtYoffset, txtDomStart, txtDomEnd}));
```

When tabbing through, the textbox `txtYoffset` is moved to the end of the tab order.  The controls are also initialized in the order specified in the Traversal Policy.  What could be the overriding logic that is to blame for what I see in this behavior?  I'm using Eclipse Mars.

Comment: How is `FocusTraversalOnArray` implemented? It is not standard JDK - is it?

Comment: I am using Eclipse, the GUI built some of that stuff auto-magically.  So I am supposing that's a good place to start digging.

Comment: It should be noted that I am willing to switch for a more "standard" method.

Comment: Can you see whether `p_1` is the focus cycle root? Use `p_1.isFocusCycleRoot`.

Comment: `System.out.println(p_1.isFocusCycleRoot());` at the end of the initialize subroutine comes back `false`

Comment: You need to check it once the frame/dialog is visible. May be add a mouse/key listener and print it in the handler.

Comment: OK, I put the line in my delete button's actionListener, it still comes back false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88441/discussion-between-kdm-and-n8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus traversal policy of a container is used only when it is the focus cycle root. Else it's parent's focus traversal policy is used. Try setting `p_1` as the focus cycle root by calling `p_1.setFocusCycleRoot(true)` in your initialisation routine.

Comment: I'm curious what will happen when I get to p_2, but I suppose I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.  Thanks for the help!